# Get from one column when other two columns have the same value

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, pandas

I need a new df with the values of the column "settings" who have same K and i. 1-1, 2-2, 3-3,4-4..

```
    K    i    Settings
0   1    1   234
1   1    2   12423
2   1    3   234234
3   2    1   2231
4   2    2   1123
5   3    2   23
6   3    3   3
7   4    1   17
```

I need the values, 234, 1123, 3, ..

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
df[df['K'] == df['i']]['Settings']
```

or shorter

```
df[df.K == df.i].Settings
```

where `df` is your dataframe.